# Find the voltage at the open circuit end of the transmisson line?

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line, homework

> [image]

In this question,i know quarter wave length line is a **Impedance inverter** line so beacause of the left sided short circuited line i will get open circuit at the mid generator,and because of the open circuited line at the left i will get short circuit at at the mid generator.
Now i am confused whether i have to consider a open circuit at the generator or a short circuit.if i take take it open circuit and calculate i will get \$0V\$ at the open circuit end,and if i take short circuit at the generator and calculate i will get \$800\angle-90 ^{\circ} V\$.

> What should be the correct and Why ? Can anyone help please?
>
> I am still confused because two high reputed users giving two different opinions.

Answer (score 1):

If one half produces an open circuit at the midpoint then forget about any influence it might have and concentrate on the quarter wave section that produces a short at the generator.

Comment: sir why are we ignoring the effect of line that is producing an open circuit at the midpoint? can you explain more,i am again confused because if one line produced the short at the mid then again the other line will produce open at the mid point. Please enlighten me sir.

Comment: An open circuit will have no effect and that is why I said to ignore it.

Comment: Thanks sir ,i have one more doubt as per my calculation i am getting \$800\angle-90 ^{\circ} V\$ but answer given \$800\angle 90 ^{\circ} V\$. i am applying the fomula from the generator \$ V(z)=cos(\beta z)V_i-jZ_Osin(\beta  z)I_i \$ is that right sir?

Comment: sir please help me in this question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/328877/find-the-current-flowing-in-the-load-of-a-transmission-line