# Find the current flowing in the load of a transmission line?

Tags: transmission-line, electromagnetic, homework

> [image]

**My Try:**

[image]

## \$Z_{in}=Z_0*\frac{Z_L+jZ_0tan\beta l}{Z_0+jZ_L tan\beta l}\$

Now

\$\beta l=\frac{2\pi\times37.5\times10^6\times10}{3\times10^8}=\frac{5\pi}{2}\$

so its becomes

\$Z_{in}=\frac{Z_0^2}{Z_L} \$

\$Z_{in}=\frac{200\times200}{100}=400\Omega\$

So for part \$(a)\$

\$I_{i}=\frac{200}{600}=\frac{1}{3}A\$ also \$V_{i}=\frac{400\times200}{600}=\frac{400}{3}\$

Now for part \$(b)\$ from the generator we know the equation for lossless line is \$ I(z)=\frac{-j}{Z_0}sin\beta z V_i+Cos\beta z I_{i}\$

so current at the load, that means at \$\lambda/4\$ distance from the generator will be
\$I=\frac{-j}{200}sin(\frac{5\pi}{2})\times\frac{400}{3}+0\times\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{3}\angle-90^{\circ}\$

but for part\$(b)\$ the actual answer is \$\frac{1}{3}\angle-90^{\circ}\$

What is the mistake i am doing can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

In part (a) you calculated the current as 1/3 so why should it suddenly be any different to the load current in part (b). As for phase angle, you have shown the line to be a equivalent to a quarter wavelength long at 37.5 MHz so, given the load is resistive, the phase angle of the load current has to be 90 degrees lagging as you have also shown.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir, but why its not coming by TL equations?

Comment: @Rohit I have no idea. One method produces X and another method produces Y. Both should produce the same OR there is a math error or formula error. I have only tried to show that your method for calculating answer (b) is incorrect based on the fact that Iin = Iout (RMS values)

Answer (score 0):

For these problems, remember that the \$z=0\$ location (highlighted in the image below) is defined at the terminals of the load. So you are looking for \$I(0)\$ in part b.

For the input impedance, you do use the length because it is some distance \$l\$ away from the load and towards the generator. This is \$z=-l\$.

[image]

Now, I don't know whether you're using the right equation (can't remember off the top of my head all the TL equations) but hopefully this points you in the right direction.